# How to pass custom variable to partial in hexo?

Tags: web, static, generator, static-site, hexo

[image: layout]

I want to create an alternating layout using the static site generator [hexo](http://hexo.io) – the text of every second post on an overview page should be on the right.

The partial I’m using needs to pass on a custom variable like `textOrientation = "left"` to the partial function.

```
<%site.tags.findOne({name: 'featured'}).posts.sort('date', -1).limit(5).each(function(post, index) {%>
    <%- partial('_partial/project-excerpt', {item: post}) %>
<% })%>
```

The template `project_excerp.ejs` then needs to generate the according classes bases on the passed variable.

My template (project_excerp.ejs):

```
<a class="???" href="/project/<%= item.slug %>"><%= item.title %></a>
```

So the questions are:

1. How can I extend the `post` variable with my own variable `textOrientation` and
2. How can I use an `if then else` in my `project_excerp.ejs`-template?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found a solution myself.

*index.js:*

```
<%site.tags.findOne({name: 'featured'}).posts.sort('date', -1).limit(5).each(function(post, index) {%>
      <% if(index % 2 === 0) { %>
            <% post.textOrientation = "left"; %>
      <% } else { %>
            <% post.textOrientation = "right"; %>
      <% } %>
  <%- partial('_partial/project-excerpt', {item: post}) %>
```

*project_excerp.ejs:*

```
<% var projectInfoClass = "ta-right"; %>
<% if(item.textOrientation === "right") {%>
  <% projectInfoClass = "ta-left"; %>
<% } %>

<a class="<%= projectInfoClass %>" href="/project/<%= item.slug %>"><%= item.title %></a>
```

Also helpful to read the [EJS](http://www.embeddedjs.com/)-docs.